# Can't add image to a button using getResource() (get NullPointerException- building project with ant)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, ant

I know that this a very common error, and I've read dozens of posts about such errors on SO already, but for some reason, absolutely nothing seems to be working out.

My ultimate object is to read an image from a particular location (in specific, the data folder) that is present at the same level as src in the project folder, and create a button with that image. However, I seem unable to read the image, and keep getting null.

Moreover, I have tried all possible combination I could think of:
gitinit.png
//gitinit.png
\gitinit.png
/gitinit.png
\gitinit.png
data/gitinit.png
data//gitinit.png
data\gitinit.png
data\gitinit.png

all out of sheer, meaningless frustration...

I'm using Eclipse. However, the project is being built with ant.

Here is the structure of my project:

[image: Project Structure]

As is visible, I've added gitinit.png everywhere possible, but to no avail.

As I read somewhere, I even tried adding data folder into the build path, but yet again, hopeless.

I realize that in this case, absolute path of the form "/data/gitinit.png" would be ideal, but here's another issue. What I'm working on is a tool for Processing. The tool is called from within Processing when it is running. When I run

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("/").getPath());
```

I get the following output:

> /C:/Program%20Files/processing-2.1.1-windows64/processing-2.1.1/lib/

(with the / before C:). This folder has the following contents:

[image: Folder contents]

but when I run

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("").getPath());
```

I get the following output:

> file:/C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Processing/tools/GitManager/tool/GitManager.jar!/git_manager/tool/

The contents of this jar file are:

[image: Jar file structure]

Here is the code I used. I've used 3 different ways of doing it (one of them came in the [Processing Tool Template](https://github.com/processing/processing-tool-template) repo's readme), though they all essentially do the same thing. Again, the ultimate aim is to load an icon onto the button.

```
// some other function that executes during runtime
        ImageIcon init = createImageIcon("gitinit.png", "git init Icon");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

    loadImage("gitinit.png");

    b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(("src\\gitinit.png")));
    System.out.println(b.getIcon());


public Image loadImage(String theFilename) {
    if (theFilename.startsWith(File.separator)) {
        return new ImageIcon(theFilename).getImage();
    } else {
        URL img;
        try{
        img = this.getClass().getResource(getPath(theFilename));
        return new ImageIcon(img).getImage();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException n)
        {
            //System.out.println("Null pointer Exception");
            n.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

    protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL;
    try{
    //imgURL = GitOptionToolbar.class.getResource(path);
        imgURL = GitOptionToolbar.class.getClass().getResource(path);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException n)
    {
        imgURL = null;
        System.out.println("null");
    }
    if (imgURL != null) {
        System.out.println("Found " + path);
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}

public String getPath(String theFilename) {
    if (theFilename.startsWith("/")) {
        return theFilename;
    }
    return File.separator + "data" + File.separator + theFilename;
}
```

**So, well, what I think is to be done is to somehow move up the present path by 3 levels, then use the relative "data/gitinit.png", or "data/tools/xyz.png", but how do I do this?**

Also, is this hypothesis correct??

I know this question is really long, and I'm sorry, I just wanted to put forth all of my experiments till now. Further, I know a lot of things are random, especially trying out different combinations of foldername, /, \ and filename, and also putting gitinit.png in every possible folder, and I apologize for that as well. Its just that I wanted to try out everything I could before posting here :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
getResource("/data/toolbar/logos/gitnit.png")
```

The complete path from `data` all the way to the image. I'n not used to using Eclispe and not used to having the *"data"* dir on the same level at the `src`. In Netbeans I have it *in* the `src`, but it looks like the Eclipse takes care of that for you, looking at your image.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work :(.  

gitinit.png is present both in the data as well as in data/toolbar folders, so I don't think that might cause an issue. Further, Eclipse didn't take care of adding data into src, that's something I manually did based on reading a few suggestions when other users had similar problems on SO.

Perhaps this problem is more related to something I'm doing wrong when building the project?

Comment: did you try and put the image into your `data.toolbar.logo` package? doing that and using path above always works for me

Comment: Yes! That worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch :)

But why did it work though?

Comment: You need to start from the root of the class path. That being the src in development environment. So the resources, to be embedded should be in the class path. Then you just use the path (fully qualified package)